# rails_admin sort_by scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am using rails_admin and I have a list of objects
 
How would I sort by `created_at >= 1.day.ago`,
ie first show all users where `created_at >= 1.day.ago` then the rest

```
list do
  sort_by :created_at # created_at >= 1.day.ago
  field :id
  field :name
  field :address
  field :created_at
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is actually a filter - sort_by only lets you order the results by a database column - whereas you want to filter out any objects that are older than a certain date.